# $S^k$ surrounding an $(n-k-1)$-plane in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: geometry, homotopy-theory, spheres

I am interested in learning what is behind the following idea, which I'm sure must have been thought about before (if it is correct). It's pretty handwavy, but here are a few examples.

First start in $\mathbb{R}$. The only hyperplane is the $0$-plane, i.e. the origin, and we can surround it by $S^0$, just two points on either side of the origin.

Then in $\mathbb{R}^2$, the $0$-plane can be surrounded by $S^1$, and a $1$-plane, a line, can be "surrounded" by $S^0$, in the sense that on both sides of the line, we can place a point.

In $\mathbb{R}^3$, we similarly have that the origin is surrounded by $S^2$, a line is surrounded (encircled) by a circle, $S^1$, and a plane is "surrounded" by two points, $S^0$.

Continuing the pattern in higher dimension without being able to visualize it, my question is

> Do we have that in $\mathbb{R}^n$,  $S^k$ "surrounds" an $(n-k-1)$-plane? (Here I would need a more proper definition of surrounding instead of relying on intuition. What would be this definition?)

Perhaps this is just a way of saying that the complement of an $(n-k-1)$-plane in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is homotopy equivalent to $S^k$, if this is true?

Comment: Realize $S^k$ as the boundary of the closed unit ball $B^{k + 1}$. Then, we could declare a (topologically) embedded copy $\iota(S^k) \subset X$ to "surround" a set $Y \subset X$ iff (1) $\iota(S^k) \cap Y = \varnothing$, and (2) for every continuous extension $\hat \iota: B^{k + 1} \to X$ of $\iota$ (that is, every continuous map $\hat \iota : B^{k + 1} \to X$ such that $\hat \iota\vert_{S^k} = \iota$), $\hat \iota(B^{k + 1}) \cap Y \neq \varnothing$.

Comment: In particular: (1) This definition coincides with the intuitive notion of "surround" in the examples in the question statement (for $X = \Bbb R^n$ and $Y = \textrm{an appropriate $(n - k - 1)$-plane}$), and (2) it is topologically invariant, i.e., preserved by homeomorphism.

Comment: This is nice. So now it remains to show that with this definition of surrounding, one can surround an $(n-k-1)$-plane with $S^k$. I'll give it a shot.

Comment: Also, is what I said about the complement being homotopy equivalent to $S^k$ true?

Comment: Good luck, and post here if you need a need a hint. As for your other question, it depends on precisely what other statement you have in mind when you say "equivalent". I think it's probably true that if $\iota(S^k)$ surrounds $Y$ in $X$, then we must have that $\pi_n(X - Y)$ is nontrivial.

Comment: I just found the answer to my other question, see the last of the examples [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homotopy#Homotopy_equivalence)

Comment: NB it's not true that if $\iota(S^k)$ surrounds $Y$ in $X$ then $Y - X$ is homotopy equivalent to $\iota(S^k)$. For example, take $X = \Bbb R^3$ and $Y$ to be the union of the $x$- and $y$-axes. If we take $\iota$ to be any map so that $\iota(S^1)$ surrounds one of the axes (and does not intersect the other), then $\iota(S^1)$ surrounds $Y$ but $\Bbb R^3 - Y$ is homotopy-equivalent to a $2$-sphere with $4$ punctures, or just as well to a thrice-punctured copy of $\Bbb R^2$, so $\pi_1(\Bbb R^3 - Y)$ is nonabelian, and in particular $\Bbb R^3 - Y$ is not homotopy-equivalent to $S^1$.